# ReactJs/Typescript: Make component state object and properties readonly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a third party class object and I want to make the properties of the object readonly. So I can not mutate the state with `this.state.object.props = "xx"`;

It looks like this

```
class ThirdPartyObject {
    id?: string;
}

interface ComponentState {
    readonly object: ThirdPartyObject;
}

this.state.object = null; // not possible
this.state.object.id = "newId"; // should also not be possible
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov It will be changed, but with `setState`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `ThirdPartyObject` fields to be readonly use `Readonly` type like:

```
class ThirdPartyObject {
  id?: string;
}

interface ComponentState {
  readonly object: Readonly<ThirdPartyObject>;
}
```

Then this:
`this.state.object.id = 'newId';`
would throw an error.